# How to pin NSWindow tabs at the left (like in Safari)?

Tags: swift, macos, tabs, appkit

I have a macOS app where the user can open document in a new tab inside the main window. But after doing this, the main window becomes a tab that can be dragged out or closed. So I am looking for a way to prevent this by locking/pinning the tab at the left of the tabbar, and disable the close button (like pinned tab in Safari) so the main interface is always accessible. 
An extra would be to disable the ability to move tabs to new windows.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Edit: this is what I want to achieve. I'm calling "main interface" the window where all the information are located (like here with the "My Library" tab). When the user clicks on an item in the table view, then the app open the pdf in a new tab, with a specific interface to display the pdf (I can achieve by opening a new window as a tab). What I want is to pin the "My Library" tab at the left so that the user can reorder pdf tabs, but always keep the "my library" tab at the same position. I also want to disable the close button of this tab (like pinned sites in Safari).
[image]

Comment: Could you post an example screenshot of your desired outcome? I'm a little confused on what you mean by "the main interface". It sounds like you want some specific set of behavior in a document pinned to the left of the toolbar, while subsequent documents in new tabs will feature some other functionality. If that were the case, then your "main interface" would not belong in a document, but perhaps a sidebar. Can you add some extra elaboration please?

Comment: I've edited my post to add an explanation to what I want to achieve.

Comment: thank you. Please correct me if I'm wrong, did your original post state that this is a document-based app? If so, I'd ask why your app needs to make use of the document architecture.

Comment: I probably confused you when I said "open document". What I meat was open pdf. I do not use a document architecture. What I have is a window containing all the app, with in the middle, a table view containing all the data. When the user double click on a row in the table view, it opens the pdf associated in a new window displaying the pdf. To make things cleaner, I chose to open this new inside a tab in the main window so that if the user open several pdf, there is only several tab. The user can then reorder them, and close them if he want, except for the tab containing the main window.

Comment: You can’t pin nswindow tabs, I recoomend that you request that feature to apple